# NameError: name 'ProductTag' is not defined

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

models.py

```
     from django.db import models
     from django.contrib.auth.models import User
     class ActiveManager(models.Model):
         def active(self):
           return self.filter(active=True)
     class Product(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True)
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2) 
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=48)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        objects = ActiveManager()
        tags = models.ManyToManyField(ProductTag, blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

        class ProductImage(models.Model):
            product = models.ForeignKey(
               Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            image = models.ImageField(upload_to="product-images")
            thumbnail = models.ImageField(
            upload_to="product-thumbnails", null=True)

     class ProductTag(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=48)
     description = models.TextField(blank=True)
     active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
     def __str__(self):
         return self.name
     def natural_key(self):
         return(self.slug,)
```

The name error says ProductTag is not defined, whereas ProductTag itself a Class. I don't understand where I missed... appreciate for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution must be like this, because I think reordering could solve your problem. However please put 2 lines of space between your classes and 1 line of space between your functions. It can make your code more readable and also more suitale for the Python guidelines.

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User


 class ActiveManager(models.Model):
     def active(self):
       return self.filter(active=True)


 class ProductTag(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=48)
 description = models.TextField(blank=True)
 active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
 def __str__(self):
     return self.name
 def natural_key(self):
     return(self.slug,)


 class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2) 
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=48)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = ActiveManager()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(ProductTag, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    class ProductImage(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(
           Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to="product-images")
        thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="product-thumbnails", null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you’re trying to use ProductTag before you’ve defined it.

You could either reorder things, or I believe you can reference by string and django will link them up later.

Eg `tags = models.ManyToManyField('ProductTag', blank=True)`